# Configuración Kiosk Microsoft Edge Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows10, edge

estoy con varios inconvenientes en una aplicación que visualizo en modo Kiosk con Microsoft Edge en Windows 10 LTSC

1. La aplicación web pide permisos de uso de webcam. En modo Kiosco no se Guarda el permiso y cada vez que se iniciar vuelve a pedir el permiso.
2. El sitio me sale como no seguro:
   Your connection isn't private.
   ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.
   Y aunque le doy advanced y Continue,
   en Kiosk no se Guarda, y cada vez que inicio me vuelve a preguntar.

Cómo puedo configurar ambos permisos desde el usuario Administrador en Microsoft Edge?,
Intente desde Local Group Policy Editor, pero no encontré nada para estos dos problemas.

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: El sitio sale inseguro porque hace falta un Certificado SSL.

Comment: Fredy buenas noches, si, solo que necesito usarlo asi.

Comment: Pero igual he probado solucionar el problema de la Camara con certificado pero ese si no se soluciona.